# Blank subreport in Jasper report

Tags: jasper-reports, subreport

I have seen quite a few questions on blank subreports but none of them provide the information I need.  I have a master report:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports"    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports  http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="sample_report"  pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="555"  leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
<property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
<property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
<property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
<parameter name="reportTitle" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="reportSubTitle" class="java.lang.String"/>
<background>
    <band splitType="Stretch"/>
</background>
<title>
    <band height="65" splitType="Stretch">
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="555" height="20"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{reportTitle}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="434" y="40" width="80" height="20"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Page "+$V{PAGE_NUMBER}+" of"]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField evaluationTime="Report">
            <reportElement x="514" y="40" width="40" height="20"/>
            <textElement/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[" " + $V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="0" y="20" width="555" height="20"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{reportSubTitle}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</title>
<pageHeader>
    <band splitType="Stretch"/>
</pageHeader>
<columnHeader>
    <band splitType="Stretch"/>
</columnHeader>
<detail>
    <band height="109" splitType="Stretch">
        <subreport isUsingCache="false">
            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="555" height="100" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true"/>
            <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
            <subreportExpression><![CDATA["sample_report_activity_report.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
        </subreport>
    </band>
</detail>
<columnFooter>
    <band splitType="Stretch"/>
</columnFooter>
<pageFooter>
    <band splitType="Stretch"/>
</pageFooter>
<summary>
    <band splitType="Stretch"/>
</summary>
</jasperReport>
```

And a subreport:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="sample_report_activity_report" pageWidth="802" pageHeight="555" orientation="Landscape" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="802" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0">
<property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
<property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
<property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
<queryString language="SQL">
    <![CDATA[SELECT ActivityType, Count, Amount, ActivityDate FROM Activity WHERE ARIID = 1]]>
</queryString>
<field name="ActivityType" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="Count" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="Amount" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="ActivityDate" class="java.lang.String"/>
<background>
    <band splitType="Stretch"/>
</background>
<title>
    <band height="24" splitType="Stretch">
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="802" height="20"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
            <text><![CDATA[Activity Report]]></text>
        </staticText>
    </band>
</title>
<pageHeader>
    <band splitType="Stretch"/>
</pageHeader>
<columnHeader>
    <band height="25" splitType="Stretch">
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="12" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
            <textElement/>
            <text><![CDATA[ActivityType]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="112" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
            <textElement/>
            <text><![CDATA[Count]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="215" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
            <textElement/>
            <text><![CDATA[Amount]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="315" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
            <textElement/>
            <text><![CDATA[ActivityDate]]></text>
        </staticText>
    </band>
</columnHeader>
<detail>
    <band height="22" splitType="Stretch">
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="12" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
            <textElement/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{ActivityType}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="115" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
            <textElement/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Count}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="215" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
            <textElement/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Amount}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="315" y="2" width="100" height="20"/>
            <textElement/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{ActivityDate}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</detail>
<columnFooter>
    <band splitType="Stretch"/>
</columnFooter>
<pageFooter>
    <band splitType="Stretch"/>
</pageFooter>
<summary>
    <band height="42" splitType="Stretch">
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="802" height="20"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
            <text><![CDATA[--- End of Activity Report ---]]></text>
        </staticText>
    </band>
</summary>
</jasperReport>
```

And I have the following Java code:

```
Map parameters = new HashMap();
parameters.put("reportTitle", "Report");
parameters.put("reportSubTitle", "Activity Date 10/25/2011");

JasperReport jasperReportMain = JasperCompileManager.compileReport("c:\\tempfilepath\\sample_report.jrxml");

JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReportMain, parameters, con);
JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint, "c:\\tempfilepath\\SampleReport.pdf");
```

As far as I can tell I have followed all the previous advice given and I still don't have any data showing up in my subreport when I run the main report.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In comments below you say that the subreport runs OK by itself. But you don't say whether the main report -- with the subreport included in it -- works OK in iReport. Does it? Start by getting that working, then figure out your Java code.

Answer (score 5):

May be the query in your subreport doesn't return any row. You might try adding `No Data` band in your subreport, put some `Static Text` in it, and set the (sub) report property `When No Data` to `No Data Section`.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't notice any irregularities from your XML JR code. 
First, are you sure your Data Source (database resultset) is returning any results and is set up properly?

I would also recommend installing the IREPORT Designer tool for Jasper Reports. I think the latest version is 4.1.2. This will help you tremendously in both designing and error/exception handling.

Comment: I did use iReport to create those jrxml files.  Also, if I print the subreport on it's own, it shows data, so I'm confident that the datasource is returning the correct results.

Comment: You might want to check the DataSource Expression attribute and then the "Connection Type" attribute of the subreport. Those should be manipulated from the Main Report's JR template (in iReport). Also, one of the main reasons of data in the subreport not showing up is how the data source for that subreport is configured from within the main report.

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong because I don't understand much jrxml as a code as I have always developed reports using iReport. Are u passing parameters from main report to subreport? If yes,just check ,by right-click on subreport that whether you have passed the parameters for your subreports.