# JasperReports subreport not displaying when parameters passed from main report

Tags: java, jasper-reports, subreport

I have one main report where parameters from java code by Map object.
In main report including one subreport and trying to pass main report parameter.

The main report and subreport working fine separately but main report does not show subreport.

Invoice.jrxml (main report):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="ma" pageWidth="683" pageHeight="899" columnWidth="643" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="1" bottomMargin="1" isSummaryNewPage="true" isSummaryWithPageHeaderAndFooter="true" uuid="51ff5174-9cb9-4d22-8e11-cd3fe9392bbd">
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.awt.ignore.missing.font" value="true"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
    <parameter name="filePath" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="imagePath" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="orderId" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="orderNum" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="orderDate" class="java.util.Date"/>
    <parameter name="billingAddress" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="121">
            <image>
                <reportElement x="8" y="0" width="314" height="50" uuid="c072a055-ead7-4e63-b87f-3d7163cf2f2b"/>
                <imageExpression><![CDATA[$P{imagePath}]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="240" y="37" width="166" height="20" uuid="7619dfad-f0f5-4c80-9f73-625cfb24d1a5"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font size="14" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["INVOICE"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="17" y="61" width="68" height="20" uuid="9d49ad56-14a9-4214-a615-3ce706cdcb0f"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["ORDER NO. "]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="85" y="61" width="7" height="20" uuid="8d44e405-3d27-421f-bd07-eeac5d84699c"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" pdfFontName="Times-Roman"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[":"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="92" y="61" width="100" height="20" uuid="5eee8a2d-9c15-4c36-887b-9baf8009901e"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{orderNum}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="488" y="61" width="79" height="20" uuid="d6eba4a3-4349-4220-ac2a-8e7ac45866d2"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["INVOICE DATE"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="568" y="61" width="7" height="20" uuid="933fae5b-6850-4620-9860-609fb4f3ae0e"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" pdfFontName="Times-Roman"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[":"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="dd-MMM-yyyy">
                <reportElement x="575" y="61" width="70" height="20" uuid="94a17726-82c9-4068-a508-faa9669bb867"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[new Date()]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="17" y="81" width="68" height="20" uuid="8193c234-a847-4db7-9f77-86cb8b7ea06e"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["PLACED ON "]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="85" y="81" width="7" height="20" uuid="b4226f3c-6c85-4a66-a86f-25f846a0c0ff"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" pdfFontName="Times-Roman"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[":"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="dd-MMM-yyyy">
                <reportElement x="92" y="81" width="100" height="20" uuid="23599627-a12c-4409-bf59-690182c93265"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{orderDate}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="488" y="81" width="79" height="20" uuid="c5382e3e-b4ae-45ca-8ed3-d78fc180730b"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["INVOICE NO. "]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="568" y="81" width="7" height="20" uuid="4c26ae03-6d88-45c6-83cd-e8144a428813"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" pdfFontName="Times-Roman"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[":"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="15" y="106" width="619" height="1" uuid="f1d3c700-6cd0-4e6f-9482-ac0de6899d6c"/>
                <graphicElement>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </graphicElement>
            </line>
        </band>
    </pageHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="54" splitType="Stretch">
            <subreport isUsingCache="false">
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="200" height="54" uuid="0b04fdb2-f4bb-4db2-935a-be96d92fa8db"/>
                <subreportParameter name="billingAddress">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{billingAddress}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{filePath} + "/BillingVenueSubReport.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="67">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="539" y="47" width="86" height="20" uuid="071f6609-ce04-405d-b993-ad0e89d95919"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Page "+$V{PAGE_NUMBER}+" of"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField evaluationTime="Report">
                <reportElement x="626" y="47" width="25" height="20" uuid="abb1c879-f261-4d0f-ba1b-7f0569d1c947"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[" " + $V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="EEE,yyy,MMMMM,dd hh:mm aaa">
                <reportElement x="67" y="47" width="168" height="20" uuid="36b23a16-1717-472c-96d7-a6f250137920"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[new Date()]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="9" y="3" width="634" height="46" uuid="ef43f479-905b-4e70-8410-3641b2ef7b73"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["#72/4, First Floor, Near Gokula Towers, Dr. MS Ramaiah Rd, HMS Layout,Gokula Extension Mathikere, Bengaluru, Karnataka 560054, Service Tax #AAICP5558PSD001, Service Tax Category Supply of Tangible Goods Service, PAN No.AAICP5558P, CIN:U74900KA2016PTC086666 Tel: 080 4114566 Web: www.powersparrow.com    © POWERSPARROW INDIA PRIVATE LIMITED"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="13" y="48" width="61" height="19" uuid="cc0b3cef-159f-4688-8325-3dfac9cb8631"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" pdfFontName="Times-Roman"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Printed On: "]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="11" y="3" width="624" height="1" uuid="f2aae4f8-1a16-4563-9ecd-38a610a3e51b"/>
                <graphicElement>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </graphicElement>
            </line>
        </band>
    </pageFooter>
    <lastPageFooter>
        <band height="108">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="542" y="0" width="101" height="24" uuid="d45e931d-45ef-42ac-b026-79d35954b03f"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Bottom">
                    <font size="12" isItalic="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Thank You !"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="EEE,yyy,MMMMM,dd hh:mm aaa">
                <reportElement x="68" y="88" width="168" height="20" uuid="547654f3-c4ff-45f7-8ad1-9f8d70b5b454"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[new Date()]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="10" y="44" width="634" height="46" uuid="7748c51f-0b9e-4d10-b80d-c44bb9c16523"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["#72/4, First Floor, Near Gokula Towers, Dr. MS Ramaiah Rd, HMS Layout,Gokula Extension Mathikere, Bengaluru, Karnataka 560054, Service Tax #AAICP5558PSD001, Service Tax Category Supply of Tangible Goods Service, PAN No.AAICP5558P, CIN:U74900KA2016PTC086666 Tel: 080 4114566 Web: www.powersparrow.com    © POWERSPARROW INDIA PRIVATE LIMITED"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="14" y="89" width="61" height="19" uuid="6d2b3804-3f20-4b5b-b7e4-04064df35dac"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" pdfFontName="Times-Roman"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Printed On: "]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField evaluationTime="Report">
                <reportElement x="627" y="88" width="25" height="20" uuid="b8c448b9-aebb-4708-ae0a-e169d30131ec"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[" " + $V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="540" y="88" width="86" height="20" uuid="73bad185-9ff2-42f1-9a05-fc18a23bb48b"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Page "+$V{PAGE_NUMBER}+" of"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="12" y="44" width="624" height="1" uuid="d8b89ce1-6581-4ce6-abf0-55fb079286e6"/>
                <graphicElement>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </graphicElement>
            </line>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="527" y="24" width="118" height="20" uuid="2a56862b-8300-460b-afb6-367fb031d6fe"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Top">
                    <font isItalic="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["For Your Business"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </lastPageFooter>
</jasperReport>
```

billingVenuSubReport.xml (Sub-report):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="MultipleReport" pageWidth="629" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="629" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0" uuid="898b61ea-06d8-443b-9332-6c4e1a9cde27">
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.awt.ignore.missing.font" value="true"/>
    <parameter name="billingAddress" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <title>
        <band height="74">
            <rectangle>
                <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" x="18" y="0" width="187" height="73" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="7b23f2bd-0dcb-45a2-95e4-30db17995322"/>
                <graphicElement>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </graphicElement>
            </rectangle>
            <rectangle>
                <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" x="205" y="0" width="193" height="73" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="b7f856b6-6047-4458-add5-5c3999db8276"/>
                <graphicElement>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </graphicElement>
            </rectangle>
            <rectangle>
                <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" x="398" y="0" width="228" height="73" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="a38c9204-bd4d-4272-a437-bdaadb824973"/>
                <graphicElement>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </graphicElement>
            </rectangle>
            <textField>
                <reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="21" y="0" width="151" height="14" uuid="3f7fecf6-3f08-458a-b64d-0b660661385e"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" isBold="true" pdfFontName="Times-Bold"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["BILLING ADDRESS"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="21" y="13" width="151" height="13" uuid="62f86f45-e16b-4e0b-ae88-658b3bdf5c57"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="9" pdfFontName="Times-Roman"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{billingAddress}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </title>
</jasperReport>
```

Java code:

```
Map<String,Object> reportParameters = new HashMap<>();
URL jrxmlUrl = this.getClass().getResource("/jrxml");
String filePath= jrxmlUrl.getPath();
String imagePath= filePath+"/logo.jpg";
reportParameters.put("filePath", filePath);
reportParameters.put("imagePath", imagePath);
setCommonParameters(reportDTO, orderInvoiceDetail, reportParameters);
setBillingLocationParameter(orderInvoiceDetail, reportParameters);
String invoiceFileName = "invoice_"+orderId+"_"+orderItemId+".pdf";
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(filePath+"/Invoice.jasper", reportParameters, new JREmptyDataSource());
Path invoiceFilePath = storageService.getFilePath(FileCategoryEnum.INVOICE, orgId, invoiceFileName);
Resource resource = new UrlResource(invoiceFilePath.toUri());
if(resource.exists()) {
   resource.getFile().delete();
}
OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(invoiceFilePath.toFile());
JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasperPrint, outputStream);
outputStream.flush();
outputStream.close();
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Blank subreport in Jasper report](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7954730/blank-subreport-in-jasper-report)

Answer (score 2):

The subreport has no data source and doesn't generate any output (by default).

There are (at least) two things that you can do.

1. Pass a `JREmptyDataSource` to the subreport (like you do for the master report in your Java code):

   ```
   <subreport isUsingCache="false">
       <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="200" height="54" uuid="0b04fdb2-f4bb-4db2-935a-be96d92fa8db"/>
       <subreportParameter name="billingAddress">
           <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{billingAddress}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
       </subreportParameter>
       <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JREmptyDataSource()]]></dataSourceExpression>
       <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{filePath} + "/BillingVenueSubReport.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
   </subreport>
   ```
2. Set `whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail"` in the subreport (at the `<jasperReport>` level).  That will result in the subreport printing all bands except the detail band when it has no data (which would do in your case because your subreport only uses the title band).